# Asymmetric Least Squares Conversion from Equation to Matrix

Tags: optimization, least-squares

In solving for asymmetric least squares baseline correction as defined in the article by Eilers and Boelens, the general equation is defined as:

$$S = \displaystyle\sum_i w_i (y_i-z_i)^2 + \lambda \displaystyle\sum_i (\Delta^2 z_i)^2$$

The paper then immediately states "The minimization problems leads to the following system of equations:'"

$$(W + \lambda D' D)z = Wy$$

where $W = \operatorname{diag} (w)$ and $Dz = \Delta^2 z$.

The problem is that I really can't figure out this transition.  I understand that we set $S=0$, but the only way I see this solving the equation is if we modify the general equation to be:

$$S = \displaystyle\sum_i w_i (y_i-z_i) + \lambda \displaystyle\sum_i (\Delta^2)^2 z_i$$

There must be some way of clearing out the variables, but I can't figure it out.  (Thanks in advance for your help!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $W = \operatorname{diag} (w)$ is nonnegative, then the quadratic cost function can be written in the form

$$\begin{array}{rl} S &= \|W^{\frac{1}{2}} (y - z)\|_2^2 + \lambda \|D z\|_2^2\\\\ &= (y-z)^T W (y-z) + \lambda \, z^T D^T D z\\\\ &= \begin{bmatrix} y\\ z\end{bmatrix}^T \begin{bmatrix} W & -W\\ -W & W\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} y\\ z\end{bmatrix} + \lambda \begin{bmatrix} y\\ z\end{bmatrix}^T\begin{bmatrix} O & O\\ O & D^T D\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} y\\ z\end{bmatrix}\\\\ &= \begin{bmatrix} y\\ z\end{bmatrix}^T \begin{bmatrix} W & -W\\ -W & W + \lambda \, D^T D\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} y\\ z\end{bmatrix}\end{array}$$

Taking the gradient of $S$ with respect to $(y,z)$, we obtain

$$\nabla S = 2\begin{bmatrix} W & -W\\ -W & W + \lambda \, D^T D\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} y\\ z\end{bmatrix}$$

As the gradient must vanish at the minimum, we obtain the following linear system

$$\begin{bmatrix} W & -W\\ -W & W + \lambda \, D^T D\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} y\\ z\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0\\ 0\end{bmatrix}$$

which yields the equation

$$(W + \lambda \, D^T D) z = W y$$

and also the equation $W y = W z$. Hence, $\lambda \, D^T D z = 0$.